# SQL Select when a grouped record has multiple matching strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large query, but my biggest problem lies in this small portion.

ItemID is foreign keyed to the Master Item table - it is not unique.  This query doesn't do what I want (row can't have all 4 names) but it illustrates what I'm looking for.

```
Select masteritemid from itemsgrouptable
where itemname like 'Item 1' 
And itemname like 'Item 2' 
And itemname like 'Item 3' 
And itemname like 'Item 4'
```

I want to pull an itemid only if the 4 listed records exist with that ID.  My current method joins the same table together 4 times based on ID, with each section looking at 1 string... it is HIGHLY inefficient.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `AND`? Because from your query it looks like you want an item that's everything since you are AND'ing everything together

Comment: I'd also argue that anything that relies on string comparison via `LIKE` can't be "highly efficient"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex match:

```
select masteritemid from itemsgrouptable
where itemname regexp 'Item [1234].*'
```

This will match any itemname starting with either "Item 1" or "Item 2" or "Item 3" or "Item 4"

Answer (score 1):

This comes up every once in a while.  Not as straightforward as I would expect.

First, don't do a "LIKE" statement if it is an exact match.  Like statements are less efficient than direct comparison.

Second, you can accomplish what you are asking in a GROUP BY / HAVING clause:

```
SELECT masteritemid FROM itemsgrouptable
GROUP BY masteritemid
HAVING COUNT(itemname) = 4
WHERE itemname IN ('Item 1','Item 2','Item 3','Item 4')
```

Basically you are grouping all of your items by the masteritemid, and restricting that grouped set where all 4 (or any number of "item #" matches) are within your specified "IN" clause.  Kind of a neat trick.

Comment: What about if they're not exact?  The 'Item 1' has the option to be wild carded, so it could be 'Floor Shine%' if they want all Floor Shine Spray, Floor Shine Wax, etc...  can you mix In and LIKE ?

Comment: If it is not an exact match, how do you know that all of your conditions are hit?

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
SELECT masteritemid FROM itemsgrouptable
WHERE itemname REGEXP '^Item[:digit]?+'
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html)